# Most accurate speech recognition for high-quality audio Spanish

Tags: audio, speech-recognition

I am starting to do research for a project, and I already found way too many tools to use, but it's hard to judge their pros and cons with no experience. I would love to either know where could I get a professional opinion on the matter of which software or API to pick (I'm not going to outdo someone with years of experience by simply doing a few weeks of research), or get some opinion of what qualities and properties a program should have to be considered.

My project consists of .wav files, recorded in a professional studio set up to get as much quality and as few interferences as possible, and I would like a reliable tool to put that in text (meaning, I give it the audio file, it returns it in some format of text file). Ideally this would be done so later on I can automate the task, but that's secondary.

The language is going to be Spanish (maybe that gives some trouble?), and the idea is to analyze the outputs, frequenzy, relationship between different recordings and so on, that's why I am worried about accuracy.

Comment: What do you mean by "outputs, frequenzy, relationship"? Is it something the tool has to give you? Or you will deduce that from the text given by the tool?

Comment: Gratis? If not, what budget?

Comment: That's what I will do once I have the speech transcripted, it's the objective of the project, but that's up to me. It'd be gratis unless I get somewhat confirmation that the tools available are not up for the task, so far I have not enough knowledge

Answer (score 1):

https://transcribe.wreally.com/guide/how-to-transcribe-semi-automatically-using-dictation/

> supports several languages including English, Spanish, Portuguese, Dutch, Chinese, French, Hebrew, Italian, Japanese, Korean and Russian. If you would like us to add support for another language please let us know.

I have used this in English for transcribing multiple voices in English.  In this case, I had to manually transcribe everything.  I have not tried the automatic version for a single speaker, in any language.  But I think this is worth a try, because I was very happy with the transcription software, and I found the company very responsive to questions and one bug report.